# Scala iterable map filter using single operation

Tags: scala, iteration

How can I perform an Iterable map and filter operations in a single operation that will return only the first yielded value that has not resulted with null?

**UPDATE 1:** I need something similar this example:

```
Range
    .inclusive(1, 10)
    .collectFirst({
        var x

        if(Random.nextBoolean())
            x = null
        else
            x = 10 

        case x if x != null => x.toString
    })
```

Can it be done with `collectFirst`?

**UPDATE 2:** I've tried the following, which uses an iterable range, but for some reason I get a Match error.

```
def SomeProcess: Boolean = {
        Random.nextBoolean()
    }

val z =
        Iterator
            .range(1, 10)
            .filter(x => {
                println(x)
                true
            })
            .collectFirst( {
                case x if SomeProcess => x.toString
            })

println(z)
```

Comment: Please, could you tell us what you have already tried.

Comment: @Adi, I could not think of a way to implement this in one operation. I've tried to tinker with collectFirst, but I couldn't make it do what I've described above.

Comment: @EranBetzalel you are on the right track: `collectFirst` does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

As @Dima alluded to you are on the right track with `collectFirst`. Use a partial function to define your condition as well as whatever kind of transformation you want to perform on the item that matches your `case` statement:

```
def f: PartialFunction[Any, String] = {
  //        Condition   Transformation
  //         |               |
  case x if x != null => x.toString
}
```

Here's a few examples of usage:

```
val l = List(1, null, 2, "Hello")
l.collectFirst(f)

res0: Option[String] = Some(1)

val l2 = Vector(null, null, null, 10)
l2.collectFirst(f)

res1: Option[String] = Some(10)
```

**UPDATE BASED ON QUESTION EDIT**

I'm not really sure which of the below options fits better for what you're requesting (I don't really know what the use case is for the question)

```
// Option 1
Range
  .inclusive(1, 10).map(i => if(Random.nextBoolean()) null else 10)
  .collectFirst({
    case x if x != null => x.toString
  })

// Option 2
Range
  .inclusive(1, 10)
  .collectFirst({
    case x if Random.nextBoolean() => 10.toString
  })
```

Since

Answer (score 0):

Using `find` for instance as follows,

```
val xs = (1 to 5).toArray
Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

xs.find(_ == 6)
Option[Int] = None

xs.find(_ > 2)
Option[Int] = Some(3)
```

This yields an `Option` with the first item that holds the predicate, or `None` otherwise.